# Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error C3872 '0x2019': this character is not allowed in an identifier

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc, visual-studio-2019

I'm new to C++ and my code is giving me the following error when I try to build the project:

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error
> C3872 '0x2019': this character is not allowed in an identifier

I am using Visual Studio 2019 Professional. I am running my code in **Release** and in my properties I am using **MFC in a static Library**. Before running the code doesn't display an errors. The lines causing the errors:

```
CString customer’sTelephoneNumber;
CString customer’sAddress;
```

Comment: `customer’sTelephoneNumber` -- get rid of the apostrophes.

Comment: Surprisingly enough `customer´sTelephoneNumber` would be legal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the `’` character (or, indeed, any punctuation marks) in the name of a variable in C++. You can only use Latin letters (upper or lower case), decimal digits ('0' thru '9'), the underscore (`_`) character and *some* Unicode characters (as detailed in the reference linked below). The first character in the name *cannot* be a digit, and names that *begin* with an underscore are best avoided, as they are often used internally by compiler implementations.

The C++ Standard is quite verbose and difficult to quote, on this matter, but there is a fairly good summary on this [cppreference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers).

Comment: The reference you linked to explains, that a whole bunch of Unicode characters are allowed to appear inside an identifier (*including* accented characters). While it's questionable whether you should be using any of those (or really anything non-ASCII), it's still perfectly legal to do so.

Comment: @IInspectable A good point, well made! I have edited my post to more fully 'conform' to that Standard, as explained in the linked reference. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Looks like you can use almost all Unicode digits, such as ႙ (U+1099 MYANMAR SHAN DIGIT NINE) or  (U+1D7E2 MATHEMATICAL SANS-SERIF DIGIT ZERO). Of course, I would not recommend you write `int x0 = 0x0;`no matter how legal it is.